# Why does Chrome on my Ubuntu (on all DE) does not have page actions?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm a Chrome extension developer, and this lack of page actions is a bit weird.

"Page action" is like the RSS icon in this image:

[image]

Chrome on my OSX works fine.

Comment: I can see page actions in Chromium that are from extensions I install, but if there are any page actions out-of-the-box, I haven't seen them.

Comment: Edit: If you block third-party cookies (at least), then there is an icon indicating that cookies were blocked.

Comment: I have 0 page actions from Chrome extensions. This is from both Chrome beta and main Chrome.

Comment: I just removed ~/.config/google-chrome-beta and ~/.config/google-chrome, and started chrome again, and still no go.

Answer (score 0):

I would look in `chrome://extensions/` in Chrome on OSX, because it appears you have an extra extension installed - [this one [image]](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-subscription-extensio/nlbjncdgjeocebhnmkbbbdekmmmcbfjd)

Here is a screenshot as well - it only works with the extension is enabled:

[image]

This might be installed by default, or integrated into Chrome on Mac (I don't know)